Marlin restarts when it starts printing in DIY 3D printer
I'm building my first 3D printer with a simple setup. I'm using:

Marlin 2.0.5
Single extruder, heatbed, and fan
Smart graphical screen
RAMPS 1.4
Arduino Mega 2560

I have tried to set up the Marlin configuration to be as close as possible to my 3D printer sizes, and I have calibrated the extruder and other stuff. But now, when I want to print a model and load it through the SD card, the bed and extruder preheat well and then do the autonomous homing, but after that, it goes a little upward and restarts Marlin again.
I tried Marlin versions 2.0.9 and 1.1.0, but the first one was the same, and the second didn't load on the graphical screen. I also get the Error: EEPROM before restarting.
What can be the problem and how can I fix it?

Is this the exact error message? Or is there more info? Please report the complete error message, and preferably add a photo of the screen. Furthermore, I'd ditch the RAMPS shield and the Arduino Mega and buy a proper controller board. The shields are pretty outdated nowadays. A new 32-bit controller board is not that expensive and might fix your problem instantly. What is the reason for not choosing the Marlin 2.1.x bugfix branch?
